# Variable inside helper function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, function, variables, helper

Progress has different boolean values, in order to return a link i want a helper function like this:

```
def progress_image(name)
      if current_user.progress.name?
        link_to blabla
      else
        link_to blabla
      end
  end
```

how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With send:

```
def progress_image(name)
  if current_user.progress.send("#{name}?".intern)
    link_to blabla
  else
    link_to blabla
  end
end
```